# How to handle and work with Non-Persistable Entities

Tags: mendix

i have a mendix project where i want to achieve the following, the user enter the page use the input area to send messages and the message appear in a list view above the input box. I created the non persistable entity in the domain model and added a list view on the page, the list view uses a microflow as source that retrive the list of objects. the input area has a button with microflow that receive the list checks if is empty, if empty create the list, create object and commit them. Still when i run the app i cant see any message appearing. What i do wrong and what can i change to achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here probably is that you somehow have to refresh the context of the page in order to retrigger the datasource of the listview that show your non persistent entities.

One approach would be to have an entity in a dataview on the page, to wich the list view items are associated. You can then refresh that object, and associate your new objects in a one-to-many relationship to that object. You can then just show the association in the listview instead of a datasource.